# image change depends on caurosel item when sliding event appers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change backgorund image when caurosel slide event trigger 
I cant file any solution in internet 
Please give me an good JS code

JS FLIE

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
             if ($('.item').hasClass('one')) {
                alert("1");
             }else if($('.item').hasClass('second')){
                alert("2");
             }else if($('.item').hasClass('third')){
                alert("3");
             }else if($('.item').hasClass('fourth')){
                alert("4");
             }
        });
```

HTML FILE :

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                  <div class="item active one">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <a class="animated-slow fadeInUp link link--nukun" href="#">Identity ca<span class="rotate">r</span>d</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="item two">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <a class="animated-slow fadeInUp link link--nukun" href="#">Electronic Signatu<span class="rotate">r</span>e pad</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="item three">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <a class="animated-slow fadeInUp link link--nukun" href="#">Finger p<span class="rotate">r</span>int Scanner</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="item four">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <a class="animated-slow fadeInUp link link--nukun" href="#">Metal K<span class="rotate">e</span>y pads</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Try this out. http://jsfiddle.net/9fwuq/ you can use on instead of bind in the example. Also why dont you check for active because all your current css selector is not specific. They will always have those classes.

Comment: this link not showing any code

Comment: jsfiddle.net/9fwuq  this link is not showing anything

Comment: Yes it is. Which browser are you using? Do you have something blocked or JS disabled? Here's an image of the page.  http://imgur.com/a/okVGk

Comment: i tried your code actually i want, when caurosel sliding immediately some output would come...but your code show result before slide finishing